# How to embed environment variables into the images with buildpack

Tags: docker, buildpack

I tryed to embed environment variables into the images like this:

```
pack build samples/java --path java/jar --env BP_JVM_VERSION=8 --env BPE_TEST_VAR=test
```

then i run the image, and attach it ,run

```
echo $TEST_VAR
```

it shows nothing

how can i  get the environment variables?

Comment: The variable you set is called BPE_TEST_VAR and the one you echo is called TEST_VAR.

Comment: it's buildpack's spectification ，see https://paketo.io/docs/reference/configuration/#image-embedded-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it's not possible using just `pack` cli. When you set the `-e/--env` flag to `pack build` you are instructing `pack` to set that environment variable at build time. It won't be part of the image or set at launch time.

You can set environment variables at launch time using the tool through which you are running your image (i.e. Docker, Kubernetes, etc...). How you do that just depends on the tool, for example with Docker, it's just `docker run -e name=val ...`.

If you want to bake the environment variable into the image itself, you need a buildpack to do that for you (at least at the moment). As was mentioned in the comments, the Paketo set of buildpacks provide [a buildpack through which you can do this](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables) and [instructions for using it can be found here](https://paketo.io/docs/reference/configuration/#image-embedded-environment-variables).

Example:

```
pack build samples/java --path java/jar --env BP_JVM_VERSION=8 --env BPE_OVERRIDE_TEST_VAR=test
```

This will override and set `TEST_VAR` to `test`. There are other options, such as append, prepend and default, instead of override, which are explained more in the docs.

As is mentioned in the docs:

> **DO NOT** embed sensitive credentials or information using the environment variables buildpack. This information is added to the image generated by your build tool, so anyone with access to the image can see what you embed using this buildpack.

Comment: When i build it did show `    [creator]         Writing env.launch/TEST_VAR.override` , but ` echo $TEST_VAR` still not work

Comment: How are you validating with `echo`? You need to invoke the launcher if you want it to set up environment variables automatically. See the first example here -> https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#user-provided-shell-process

Comment: Let me be clear. As you said `If you want to bake the environment variable into the image itself, you need a buildpack to do that for you (at least at the moment). As was mentioned in the comments, the Paketo set of buildpacks provide a buildpack through which you can do this and instructions for using it can be found here.`   above,  I did use the `paketo-buildpacks/environment-variables` cause my deault builder is `paketobuildpacks/builder:base` , then i set the -env with BPE_* when pack build .  But when i run the image, and i run `echo $var` , still not print my environment variable.

Comment: Are you running `docker run -it my-cool-image echo "$var"`? or are you running `docker run --entrypoint launcher -it my-cool-image echo "$var"`? It's critical that you include the launcher. The launcher knows how to source all of the environment variables and ensure they are set properly before your command runs. If you skip the launcher, none of the env variables you set will be available. It sounds like that is what's happening.